# Changing x position of SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, position

I am running a for loop in my game that would generate SKSpriteNodes.

I want my first block to start at (20, 40) and add 20 to the x position and 40 to the y position for every new block.

First block (20, 40)
Second block (40, 80)
Third Block (60, 120)
And so on.

The y position is behaving the way I want to, however the x position would randomly start anywhere on my screen then add 20 for every new block generated.

Below is my code.

```
       func generateBlocks() {

            for _ in 1..<5 {

                xP += 20
                yP += 40

                let xx = CGFloat (xP)
                let yy = CGFloat (yP)

                print("x position: \(xx)")
                print("y position: \(yy)")

                let resourcePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Blocks", ofType: "sks")
                let blocks = MSReferenceNode(URL: NSURL (fileURLWithPath: resourcePath!))

                blocks.goals.position = CGPoint (x: xx,y: yy)
                addChild(blocks)
    }

    }
```

I also added the print statement of how it would look like when I run the code.

Below is the print statement of the x and y positions of the blocks.
[image]

I tried switching the order of the xP and yP initializing. That didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post where you define xP and yP? The first thing you're doing to them is adding to their values, but we can't see what they start at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer to use [while loops](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html) for this kind of operations where you must impose a condition from start, for example limits:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    let deltaX:CGFloat = 20.0
    let deltaY:CGFloat = 40.0
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        let widthLimit = self.frame.width-40
        let heightLimit = self.frame.height-140
        let startX:CGFloat = 80.0
        drawStair(startX,limits:CGSizeMake(widthLimit,heightLimit))
    }
    func drawStair(startFromX:CGFloat,limits:CGSize) {
        var currentX:CGFloat = startFromX
        var currentY:CGFloat = startFromX+deltaY
        while currentX<limits.width && currentY<limits.height {
            drawBlock(CGPointMake(currentX,currentY))
            currentX += deltaX
            currentY += deltaY
        }
    }
    func drawBlock(position: CGPoint,size:CGSize = CGSizeMake(40,40)) {
        let block = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.redColor(), size: size)
        block.position = position
        block.name = "block"
        addChild(block)
    }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: This is a great solution, however the reason why I used a for loop is so I can create a switch statement inside the loop where I can switch between adding and subtracting the x position by 20 pixels. I'm not sure if I can do that with a while loop and to be honest I don't understand it that well. But I will accept this as the right answer because it does answer my initial question. Thank you!

Comment: Never mind, I'm able to do what I want to do. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I've used while because conceptually you dont' draw n elements, you want to draw elements with limits so limits control this loop from the start position